# Is the power set of a subset of rational numbers denumerable? Could you please prove it?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The power set of given subset A of rational numbers is denumerable? How can I prove it?

A = {x ∈ Q : 2 ≤ x ≤ 5}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $\mathbb Q$ is dense, $A$ is countable infinite. According to Cantor theorem, the cardinality of the power set of a set $S$ is greater than the cardinality of $S$.

The cardinality of the power set of $A$ is therefore not countable.

Answer (score 1):

Any infinite subset of the rationals is countably infinite, so can be put in bijection with the naturals.  The power set of the naturals is not countable.